# Exponential Distruproblem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution

Four tigers in a reserve forest are monitored using geo tags. The waiting times for responses from 4 tigers in the reserve follow an iid exponential distribution with mean 3. If the system has to locate all 4 tigers within 5 minutes, it has to reduce the expected response time of each geo tag. What is the maximum expected response time that will produce a location for all four tigers within 5 minutes or less with at least $90%$ probability.

I don’t understand this question, can someone explain what it is asking for and provide the solution?

Comment: Let $X_1,\dots,X_4$ be the response time for the $4$ tigers. Those random variables are iid exponentially distributed with mean $3$. Now we have
$$
P(\max(X_1,\dots,X_4) \leq 5) < 0.9.
$$
But you want that probability to be $\geq 0.9$. To achive that, you can change the mean of the exponential distributions to any $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$. How big can you choose $\mu$ such that the above probability is $\geq 0.9$?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to find the distribution of the max of exponential RVs. Let $X_n \sim exp(\lambda)$ be i.i.d. RVs and let $Y = \max_n \{X_n\}$.

$P(Y \leq y)$

$=P(\max_n \{X_n\} \leq y)$

$=P(X_1 \leq y, \; X_2 \leq y, \; ..., \; X_n \leq y)$

$=P(X_1 \leq y)^n$ (using independence)

$=(1-e^{-\lambda y})^n$ (using definition of exponential CDF)

In your example, $n=4$, so you can compute $\lambda$ from the inequality $P(Y \leq 5) \geq 0.9$, i.e. $(1-e^{-5 \lambda})^4 \geq 0.9$.